# Angular: How to make an element that will close UI bootstrap dropdown on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using [Angular UI](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) with bootstrap and I'm using the uib-dropdown.  I have auto-close set to outside click, but I want to also create a button in the dropdown that will close it. I tried adding `uib-dropdown-toggle` to one of the elements but that broke the drop down completely (it wouldn't open at all). How do I create an element that closes the drop down menu? 
Relevant code:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-append-to-to-body">
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <!-- This is the button I want to close the dropdown -->
    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">X</button></li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `is-open` attribute to control with and angular variable the "openness" of the dropdown. Then you can programmatically set this variable value to `false` to close the dropdown.

Here is an example from your code:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-append-to-to-body" is-open="dropdownIsOpen">
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <!-- This is the button I want to close the dropdown -->
    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="dropdownIsOpen = false">X</button></li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This did not work.  Isn't the `is-open` in the scope of the directive itself and not the controller that the view is using?  Is that why its not working?

Comment: Nevermind, got it working I had some extra html I forgot to include, I needed to add the `is-open="dropdownIsOpen"` to the button that opens the drop down not to the `uib-dropdown-menu` div.